# How to make truffle compile subfolders?

Tags: truffle

I have a Solidity project. It has contracts folder and few subfolders. Now I have to compile it with Truffle, but it seems to me the tool doesn't support the case when contracts are not in "contracts/" folder.

I've found it could be done via solc options in truffle.js, but I can't figure out what should I place there. Could you help me? Thanks

Comment: You can `require` them in the main contract to get it compiled.

Comment: No, this is not what I'm looking for. `require` checks a statement and I'm talking about a project with few levels of directories. Truffle thinks every contract is in "contracts/" directory, but in my case there are "contracts/foundation/", "contracts/common/" etc

Comment: Looks like your requirement is not to get the contract deployed/compiled but  to arrange the contracts in folder and then do deploy/compile. If it is multiple contracts, you can use the migrations file to get it compiled and deployed.

Comment: Also consider reading [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)

Comment: Ok, let me explain again. I've already have a contracts folder with subfolders. I can compile it with solc and its options. Smart-contracts have "import ...." and it has subfolder's name. So now I have to create ethpm package. Truffle can do it, but only when *.sol files are int contracts folder, not subfolders

Answer (score 2):

As i understand your problem it can be simply stated as follows:

This could be your Dapp structure:

```
my-app
app
contracts
migrations
node_modules
test
```

Now you have these

```
contract\foundation\foundation.sol
contract\common.sol
contract\somethingElse\SomeOther.sol
```

When you run

```
truffle compile
```

It doesn't compile all of them, only those directly accessible.

Now your simple solution, run this:

```
truffle compile --all
```

this commands tells truffle to look for every `.sol` extension file anywhere in `contracts` folder and compile it.

Comment: Ok, thanks! That's something. Unfortunately after this there was another issue. Now I have to `publish` my contracts to ethpm. The issue is described here https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/issues/699 but nobody answers

Comment: You can't do that. You cannot combine all the dependencies into a single package. If you have ever installed a NPM package then you might have noticed that all the dependencies are installed separately,and then they are used by combining them, similarly you need to publish them separately, and when some body installs your main package he would also download and install its dependencies, for the main package to work. This approach is much better and makes debugging easy.